# What's the difference between glib gunichar and wchar_t and which is better for cross-platform solutions?

Tags: c, unicode, cross-platform, glib, wchar-t

I'm trying to write some C code which is portable only so far as the user has `gcc`, and has `glib` installed.

From all my research, I've found that with `gcc`, a `wchar_t` is always defined as 4 bytes, and with `glib` a `gunichar` is also 4 bytes.

What I **haven't** figured out is if like a `gunichar`, a `wchar_t` is encoded as UCS4 as well. Is this the case? If so, I *should* be able to simply cast a `gunichar*` to a `wchar_t*` and use the `stdc wcs*` functions, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use GLib, don't use `wchar_t`. Use its unicode support, it's *a lot* better than the C standard library's support.

`wchar_t` is 4 bytes on Linux and Mac OS (and a few others), not on Windows (it's 2 bytes there) and some others. Portable code means avoiding `wchar_t` like the plague.

Comment: hmm. thanks. i just noticed that almost all of the glib unicode functions operate on utf8 strings, and from what I understand (could be wrong) iterating through a multi-byte encoded char array is inefficient as you need to use an iterator to make sure you get a full char and simply not a byte (can't simply i++ you way through the array).  I just now re-checked the docs and g_utf8_next_char() is implemented as a  macro, so I guess it's not so much of an issue to me anymore. thanks again.

Comment: @skot decent unicode support is costly, any way you put it. Worry about performance once your program/library works, not before.

Comment: good point. things seem to be working well so far, so I'll cross that bridge if/when I need to. thanks again.