# Why would anyone use gboolean (GLib) instead of bool type?

Tags: c, glib

I've been reading some code which uses `gtk+` and I've encountered types like `gboolean` and `gunichar`.

As long as I can understand the point of using `gunichar` instead of `wchar_t` ([glib gunichar and wchar_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850553/glib-gunichar-and-wchar-t)), I can't really understand the point of using `gboolean` instead of `bool`.

### Question: What's the point of using `gboolean` instead of `bool`? Is there something more than just being careful about the code style consistency?

It wouldn't be so weird to me if it were used for a general consistency (*if one decides to use `GLib`, one'll prefer to use types defined there*). However the author of that code uses `int` instead of `gint`. Is the author just being careless?

---

Just to add more details ([official GLib as a reference](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)):

- `gunichar` is defined as `typedef guint32 gunichar`
- `guint32` is defined as `typedef unsigned int guint32`
- `gboolean` is defined as `typedef gint gboolean`
- `gint` is defined as `typedef int gint`

Comment: I don't know if GLib is designed to be used with versions of C older than C99, if it is, then there you'd have a reason for having `gboolean` - because there wouldn't be a standard boolean type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does glib redefine types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819561/why-does-glib-redefine-types)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uniformity and maintainability. If at a certain point in future a new `utf8char` type is introduced, it will only be a matter of changing the `typedef` and recompiling, without having to go through thousands of lines of code to patch every single usage.

Also consider that GLib is meant to work on a wide range of compilers, not all fully compliant with the latest specs. For instance, the availability of `bool`, `wchar_t` and fixed-size types cannot be assumed, since they all came with C99 and C11. Furthermore, GLib development began in 1998 (as you can see from the [contributors graph](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/graphs/contributors)), when C99 was still in draft and those features weren't even standard.

Answer (score 6):

Recently discovered it's not just merely about consistency; there is actually caveat involved when dealing with *big endian* platforms.

On big endian platforms tested so far (PowerPC32, Sparc64, etc) `g_option_context_parse()` would fail to deal with argument declared with C99 `_Bool`, as if the relevent options were completely ignored. Switch to `gboolean` and everything works again. This problem is not present in little endian platforms.

I'm not sure if it's intentional behavior, but the internal parsing of `G_OPTION_ARG_NONE` type arguments are all handled using `gboolean`, which is equivalent to native integer in terms of occupied byte size, while `_Bool` occupies 1 byte only. Probably that explains the problem under big endian environment.

Comment: On little-endian, passing &bool for G_OPTION_ARG_NONE when parsing array of GOptionEntry may cause an overrun where adjacent array fields get clobbered with some zeros.